# How many partitions are allowed in different SSAS versions

Tags: ssas

How many partitions are allowed in SSAS. I read there should be 1 partition for 1 measure group and for each partition the number of records should not be more than 20 million rows but this is for prior ssas 2005. I tried to get it from msdn also. There is is mentioned max size is 2 ^ 31 -1 . What size this refers to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is - it depends on your Edition of SQL Server.
If you have Standard Edition, you can have max 3 partitions per measure group, only 1 of the partitions will be available to you.

According to [MS Capacity Specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/olap-physical/maximum-capacity-specifications-analysis-services?view=sql-analysis-services-2017), in Enterprise edition of SSAS you can have no more than 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647 **partitions in a cube**. So sum all partitions in all cube measure groups.

20 million rows per partition is some rule of thumb on partition design; some boundary value when consider partitioning measure group.

Comment: Thanks Ferdipux. I referred to the same specification website but the figures were looking weird.